# How to wrote .htaccess rule that redirects to another domain while preserving and mapping file path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to write an .htaccess to redirect URLs on my site to URLs on another site, while preserving part of the file path, and converting another part of the file path to query string values. Here are two examples of what I want to do:

Example #1:

File path on my site: "/redirects/025/0257002/0257002_03/file01.ts/AAA/BBB/CCC"
Redirect to: "http://otherdomain.com/025/0257002/0257002_03/file01.ts?Policy=AAA&Key-Pair-Id=BBB&Signature=CCC"

Example #2:

File path on my site: "/redirects/000/0007001/0007001_01/file02.ts/DDD/EEE/FFF"
Redirect to: "http://otherdomain.com/000/0007001/0007001_01/file02.ts?Policy=DDD&Key-Pair-Id=EEE&Signature=FFF"

Please note that in the above scenario, the part of the path represented by "025/0257002/0257002_03" could change, but will maintain the same structure. In addition, the values in the part of the path that maps to file and query string values (ie., "file01.ts/AAA/BBB/CCC") could change as well, while maintaining the same structure.

I've tried and failed to figure out the best way to do this. Please note that performance is very important. So, I'm trying to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance for your help writing the appropriate htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either mod_alias or mod_rewrite. You can add these rules in the htaccess file in the document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/redirects/([0-9/_]+)/([^/]+)\.ts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://otherdomain.com/$1/$2.ts?Policy=$3&Key-Pair-Id=$4&Signature=$5
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^redirects/([0-9/_]+)/([^/]+)\.ts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://otherdomain.com/$1/$2.ts?Policy=$3&Key-Pair-Id=$4&Signature=$5 [L,R=301]
```

If you already have rewrite rules in your htaccess file, you'll want to stick with using mod_rewrite and add the rewrite rules above any rules you may already have.